# How to pass a print command from Android Emulator to Printer which is configured with the same Computer

Tags: android, printing

I have written a code which take image from gallery and set this image for printing using print APIs.
I want to fire a print command from Android Emulator and it will give direct print to the printer which is configured to the same Computer and attached to the same LAN network.
I do not want to use Google Account for these connection. 
Is there any working solution to print any image or doc from emulator to printer or is there any driver present which can connect my Printer and Emulator in Same LAN ?

please reply

Thank You.

Comment: Please see my question :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094911/how-to-give-print-command-to-printer-from-android-app

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a network printer and will accepts Socket connections. You need to have your printer IP address to be able to connect to it and use this connection OutputStream to write text/files to be printed.

```
Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);
PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
outputStream.println("\fThis is a test print");
outputStream.close();
socket.close();
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. can you elaburate more. is there any driver or API prsent for the connection? I need the windows dependancy for the connection. if you have any example or know any link, please share it. thank you.

Comment: You should not need any drivers, check my update. You can also use the new printing APIs added to KitKat 4.4+ http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html if that an option

Comment: Hi Mostafa Gazar, as per your suggestion I have tried with the socket connection. but I got following error.

Comment: 11-18 05:34:40.610: W/System.err(1874): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /(IP Address) (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
                                                                                 My focus is to Print any Image or Doc file from Android Emulator to LAN Printer. I have tried with Printer APIs also. Thanks

Comment: @Mostafa Gazar Please check my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094911/how-to-give-print-command-to-printer-from-android-app