# How to give print command to printer from Android app?

Tags: android, printing, ip, port, network-printers

I have created a simple app in which I give print command to printer but nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Socket socket;
        try {
            socket = new Socket("xxx.xxx.xx.21", 515);
            PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.println("\fThis is a test print");
            outputStream.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

When I run this code it works but doesn't print anything on printer.

**Configuration details:**

I have my laptop, android device & printer in same network. I tested IP addresses of all the 3 as well as port number of printer. Also, I pinged to printer's IP address from my laptop command prompt so I get reply but when I connect through device nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry I could not get result for printing using wi-fi. I have done GoogleCloudPrinting but Project was on hold so I never tried again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please share links to achieve it using GoogleCloudPrinting?

Comment: I don't have any link handy but [GoogleCloudPrint](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android) might help you or search on google.

Comment: Why did you come up with using port 515?  Did you try to telnet to 515 (from your laptop)? Did you get any response? Did you manage to print your line when submitting the given command via telnet? Why do you start command with "\f" (form feed, ascii 12)? Which docs did you get it from?

Comment: Looks like 515 is LPD protocol http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Printer_Daemon_protocol (which doesn't seem to have many good fresh examples on the web, so I wonder where did it come from?)

Comment: Also RFC document for LPD http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1179.txt says `All commands begin with a single octet code, which is a
   binary number which represents the requested function.  The code is
   immediately followed by the ASCII name of the printer queue name on
   which the function is to be performed.` so this makes think that maybe you need to play with telnet and figure out which LPD command would actually print desired result, and then simply implement it in android. HTH

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please tell how can I use telnet with socket?